# Laravel QueryBuilder where clause with user info on other model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Model ImageRequest that is related to my User model like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

An my User model like this:

```
public function imageRequests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ImageRequest');
}
```

Now I use this package to build my filterable query to fetch all ImageRequests:

[spatie/laravel-query-builder](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder)

this is what my query looks like:

```
$query = QueryBuilder::for(ImageRequest::class)
        ->with(['requestTypes'])
        ->allowedIncludes('requestTypes')
        ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'new') desc")
        ->orderBy('functional_id', 'asc')
        ->allowedFilters(
            'id',
            'pv_number',
            'created_at',
            Filter::scope('starts_between'),
            'location_of_facts',
            'train_nr',
            'status',
            'result_of_search',
            Filter::custom('type', RequestTypeFilter::class)
);
```

I need to add a where clause for the User model something like this:

```
->where('zone', Auth::user->zone);
```

But it says:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'zone' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `image_requests` where `zone` = a)

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this code, Here I added a whereHas instead for where. so it will take only matching records to user table for desired zone.

hope it helps..

```
$query = QueryBuilder::for(ImageRequest::class)
     ->with(['requestTypes'])
     ->whereHas('user'=>function($q){
         $q->where('zone', Auth::user->zone);
      })
      ->allowedIncludes('requestTypes')
      ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'new') desc")
      ->orderBy('functional_id', 'asc')
      ->allowedFilters(
         'id',
         'pv_number',
         'created_at',
          Filter::scope('starts_between'),
          'location_of_facts',
          'train_nr',
          'status',
          'result_of_search',
           Filter::custom('type', RequestTypeFilter::class));
```

Please have try this, used direct join query.

```
$query = ImageRequest::selectRaw('column1,column2') 
        ->join('user', function($join){
            $join->on('ImageRequest.user_id','=','user.id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('request_types', function($join){
            $join->on('request_types.image_request_id','=','image_request.id')
        })
        ->where('user.zone', Auth::user->zone)
        ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'new') desc")
        ->orderBy('functional_id', 'asc')
        ->allowedFilters(
                'id',
                'pv_number',
                'created_at',
                Filter::scope('starts_between'),
                'location_of_facts',
                'train_nr',
                'status',
                'result_of_search',
                Filter::custom('type', RequestTypeFilter::class)
        );
```

Comment: This creates a subquery instead of using an inner join no?

Comment: yes, if your are using with, you can not use direct join(based on my knowledge).
or else you have to do direct queries. Reply if you need help on direct join queries.